# I try to find a detect array of circles using findCirclesgrid in open cv, but i doesn't work

Tags: python, opencv

I try to detect array of circles in below picture.
Luckily, I found a python code in the internet. However, It doesn't work and I have no idea what the problems are. Please let me know the fine solutions and introduce the simple method to detect all the circles array in a picture.

This is the code I found in the internet

```
import numpy as np
import cv2 as cv

img = cv.imread('circles0.png')
gray = cv.cvtColor(img, cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
ret, corners = cv.findCirclesGrid(gray, (4,9), None, flags = cv.CALIB_CB_ASYMMETRIC_GRID)
if ret == True:
    corners2 = corners
    # corners2 = cv.cornerSubPix(gray,corners, (11,11), (-1,-1), (cv.TERM_CRITERIA_EPS + cv.TERM_CRITERIA_MAX_ITER, 30, 0.001))
    cv.drawChessboardCorners(img, (4,9), corners2, ret)
    cv.imwrite('output.jpg', img)
    cv.imshow('img', img)
    cv.waitKey(0)
```

[image]

Comment: your circles are to big.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you are using is looking for a rectilinear grid of circles, 4 rows by 9 columns.

[image]

The image your using doesnt match that criteria.

To find circles anywhere in an image [Hough Circle Transform](https://docs.opencv.org/master/dd/d1a/group__imgproc__feature.html#ga47849c3be0d0406ad3ca45db65a25d2d) is probably your best bet for your image.

Try the following & be aware that the parameters in `cv2.HoughCircles()` is very image sensitive.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread('circles0.png',0)
img = cv2.medianBlur(img,5)
cimg = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)

circles = cv2.HoughCircles(img, cv2.HOUGH_GRADIENT, 1, 70,
                           param1=50, param2=30, minRadius=0, maxRadius=0)

circles = np.uint16(np.around(circles))
for i in circles[0,:]:
    # draw the outer circle
    cv2.circle(cimg,(i[0],i[1]),i[2],(0,255,0),2)
    # draw the center of the circle
    cv2.circle(cimg,(i[0],i[1]),2,(0,0,255),3)

cv2.imshow('detected circles',cimg)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Ouput,

[image]

Comment: the circles grid methods don't use hough transform but a blob detector that filters for circularity.